# Combining dataframe year and month into new object Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, dataframe

I have a dataframe with separated columns of just Year and Month like:

```
Year        Month
2001        1
2001        2
2001        3
.
.
2010        1
2010        2
.
```

Converting to `pd.datetime` using `pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month']])` requires days to match the format so I get the error:

`ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day] is missing`

I felt like I could just fill a new column with Day = 1 repeated but I would like to avoid this because I want to create a time series by the Year-Month only.

Is there a way to map Year-Month to a date to graph properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not such thing as a month only `datetime` thingy.

#### `pd.to_datetime`

`assign` creates a copy of `df` with the columns as specified in the arguments`.

As [@timgeb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271332/combining-dataframe-year-and-month-into-new-object-python#comment93426200_53271340) stated:

> Explanation: `df.assign(day=1)` is a quick way to create a temporary dataframe with a `'day'` column without having to modify your original dataframe.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1))

0   2001-01-01
1   2001-02-01
2   2001-03-01
3   2010-01-01
4   2010-02-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

### `to_period`

You may want to use `to_period`.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1)).dt.to_period('M')

0   2001-01
1   2001-02
2   2001-03
3   2010-01
4   2010-02
dtype: object
```

Comment: Explanation: `df.assign(day=1)` is a quick way to create a temporary dataframe with a `'day'` column without having to modify your original dataframe.

Comment: I've got values associated with each year and month. I know this wasn't addressed in the original question but is there a way to make these temp values inside the dataframe? It works if I keep the original index, slice it off as a separate df and then add them back into the original df.

Comment: IIUC: `df.assign(MonthPeriod=df[['Year', 'Month']].assign(day=1).dt.to_period('M'))`

Comment: @HelloToEarth if that isn't what you meant, you'll need to clarify.  I'm sure the answer is, yes but I need to understand what you mean first (-: